# Specialized Brain problem

Tags: suspension

I have been searching for a while regarding a problem with my Specialized Brain. Here is the story..

I bought a 2008 Specialized Stumpjumper Expert 2nd hand and immediately noticed air in the shock. The brain hose was loose and so off it went to a place (not Fox or Specialized) to get rebuilt. I got it back and it was fine for a while but then after about 20hrs I noticed a lumpiness in the compression stroke. It seemed to be a judder, or like a notch. I sent it back, rebuilt, same problem.

Is it air in there? Or do you think it is the brass inertia mass out of tolerance in its sleeve and hence fluttering?

I am planning to take it back from the chap who is rebuilding, strip it, check the tolerance, machine a new mass if needed and then rebuild.

If you have any idea about what it could be, would be grateful. Also if anyone could help with any instruction on the strip and re-build, would be even cooler.

Comment: Have you removed the shock from the frame and checked the movement in the frame to make sure there isn't an issue with the frame bearings?

Comment: Hi there, yes it had new bearing in it, plus I have a spare non brain shock which I have been using for several months now with no problems. :( It is in the shock. Manifests itself only when I really jump on the pedals at about 2/3 stroke. Rebound is fine so I was thinking that it is something in the compression circuit.

Comment: Ashley - can you give us an update on your shock problem?  Its considered okay to answer and accept your own question.  Also answering will help anyone else who has the same issue in the future.

Comment: Ashley, there is a known problem with these shocks.  As it is a Brain shock, it should be returned to a Specialized dealer for replacement. If you're lucky, at no cost, but that depends on you having proof of purchase. Technically, the shock is out of warranty, but I've had good luck getting the replaced anyway, since the problem is well known. Unfortunately, since it is a proprietary shock design, Specialized will not share detail of the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I bought the bike used and it's really old, in the end I just bought a monarch xx to replace it. :(